# Javascript passing/chaining a promise using async/await

Tags: javascript, async-await

Is it possible in Javascript to await a promise that has already been sent but possibly not yet resolved ?

```js
async function doStuff(nth) {
  setTimeout(() => console.log(nth), 2000);
}


async function waitForMe(prom, callback, nth) {
  await prom;
  await callback(nth);
}


const v = doStuff(1);
waitForMe(v, doStuff, 2);
```

The code above executes in parallel; for my problem the user may call doStuff  at runtime again before it completes and must execute sequentially.

Comment: That definitely won't work as is since there's no promise anywhere.

Comment: @Countingstuff - sure there is. The async function returns a promise by nature.

Comment: Right sure sorry, I mean an explicit one. I don't see that there's any way to make use of that fact unless you have an explicit promise somewhere so that you can use await or .then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not do like this?

```js
function doStuff(nth) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(nth);
      resolve("done");
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function waitForMe(prom, callback, nth) {
  await prom;
  await callback(nth);
}

const v = doStuff(1);
waitForMe(v, doStuff, 2);
```

Comment: This works thankyou. But I am unsure why I have to declare the promise return explicitly doesn't the async syntactic sugar return a promise anyway ?

Comment: Sure, burt the async function you had before resolved basically instantly, it resolved because it hit the bottom of the body very quickly due to no awaits, the promise I put in means it doesn't resolve until the callback on setTimeout executes. Also to note, since the top function doesn't actually do anything asynchronous it doesn't need to be marked async.